# Configuring ARM template to deploy Azure Steam Analytics with Power BI as Output

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-stream-analytics

I am using ARM template to create ASA with PowerBI as output. I am following the JSON structure for Power BI in the link below. However, I am curious to know what values need to be given for

```
"groupId": "string",
"groupName": "string"
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.streamanalytics/streamingjobs/outputs

For testing, I gave random values for groupName and groupId and when I use this template to run in Power Shell, I keep getting errors similar to "The JSON provided in the request body is invalid. Property 'groupId' value 'abcdefabcdefabcdefabcdefabcdefabcdef' is not acceptable."

Comment: Found this link and its very useful - https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/david/2017/07/20/building-azure-stream-analytics-resources-via-arm-templates-part-2-the-template/  . Issue solved :)

Comment: Please post your own answer.